# Get-Dhcpserverv4XXX invalid class cimException

Tags: powershell

dhcpserverv4reservation cmndlit but im getting a Invalid class cimExcetion Error `Get-dhcpserverv4reservation -computername 192.168.x.x`
any help wouls be appreciated

Comment: You have a computer with a host name of `192.168.x.x`? I didn't think that was possible.  Perhaps you mean `-IPAddress 192.168.x.x` where x is some value?

Comment: no thats just an example my IP starts with 180....

Answer (score 0):

somehow the windows feature got uninstalled i just needed to reinstall it